# HTML Button contain two names

Tags: php, html, forms

I am trying to make the button in my form contain two names. Let me explain.

I have 2 buttons, the first one has a value of 1, and the other one has a value of 2. They are both connected to the post method "Click". But I need my "$pos = $_POST['position']" to become the value of the button. Is that possible?

What I tried was `<button name="click" name="position" type="submit">` but it's not working

Comment: Refresh the page

Comment: Button has just one name attribute.

Comment: Can your two buttons be radio buttons?

Comment: No, they need to be buttons because I want the post method to execute when clicking them.

Comment: Ever consider looking into using some js/jquery? :) You can make it send the right value, with the right name, based on whatever you click in the page (button, element, graphic, or whatever you desire).

Comment: Uhm, isn't there a more simple way just to give the $pos variable the value of the button?

Comment: too many ways to fix this. I have my own ideas.

Comment: Please include a [mcve] of your markup. Is there a reason you can't use two separate forms for these buttons which could then contain different `<input type="hidden">` elements?

Comment: Give both buttons the same name but different value.

Answer (score 4):

No element can have two attributes with the same name (i.e. you cannot have two attributes named `name` on one element). Some attributes take a space-separated list of values, but `name` is not one of them.

Pick either `click` or `position` to be the name of the button, and **change your server-side code** so that it recognises data with that name as representing both pieces of information that you were trying to convey.

You'll probably want to add a `value` attribute too.

Comment: How can I make my variable $pos equal the value of the button with only one attribute?

Comment: @OmegaCebbo — `$pos = $_POST['XXX']` where XXX is whichever of the two names you pick. (Assuming the button is in a form with method=post)